# how to anchor the sentence words that are in the array too

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to anchor the sentence words that are in the array.

```
<?php
$names = array('sara', 'max', 'alex');
foreach ($names as $dt) {
    $name = '@' . $dt;
    $text = preg_replace('/(' . $name . '\s)/', ' <a href=' . $dt . '>\1</a> ', $text);
}
echo $text;
?>
```

when my sentence like this it works well.

```
 $text = "@sara @alex @max";
```

but when my sentence like this

```
$text = "hello @sara hello @max hello @alex";
```

it doesn't work well.

Comment: But your name already have the `@` in you example. Is that the problem?

Comment: before concatenating: `$name = '@'.$dt;` check first symbol of `$dt` for `@`

Comment: Define "doesn't work well". From this snippet it seems that you should replace `\s` with `\b` (word anchor) - but then it's not clear why it 'works' in the first case.

Comment: this looks like something that can be a lot easier to solve using a simple string replacement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever the string you use, you don't reach a satisfactory outcome because:

- a name at the end of the string isn't replaced
- you obtain duplicate spaces around the replaced items
- there's a trailing space at the end of the href attribute
- you need one pass per name to proceed a single string

That's why I suggest to do all replacements in one pass and to use a negative lookahead to check if the next character is a white-space or the end of the string:

```
$text = "hello @sara hello @max hello @alex";

$names = array('sara', 'max', 'alex');

$pattern = '~@(' . implode('|', $names) . ')(?!\S)~';
$text = preg_replace($pattern, '<a href="$1">$0</a>', $text);
```

Note that you can replace `(?!\S)` with `(?!\w)` (or `\b`, depending of what characters are allowed in names).